# Replace spaces from text (multiple lines)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm preparing a some data.txt to use as csv. My data is as follows:

```
 0    PT  TY LAB    PAR(0)        L2-NORM         U(1)          U(2)          U(3)          U(4)          U(5)          U(6)     
   1     1   9   1   3.00000E+01   1.41129E+02   1.50000E+00  -3.33011E-11   3.59422E+01   5.05825E-10   1.23750E+02   1.05732E-09
   1    -2   0   0   2.99960E+01   1.41123E+02   1.49980E+00   0.00000E+00   3.59238E+01   0.00000E+00   1.23750E+02   0.00000E+00
```

if I use

```
with open('data.txt', mode='r') as csv_file:
 csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
 line_count = 0
 for row in csv_reader:
     if line_count == 0:
         print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
         line_count += 1
     print(row)
     line_count += 1
```

I will get **one column** instead of 12.

I started by using data.strip() to remove whitespaces from both the left and the right.
Then, I want replace the whitespaces by commas to read correctly the data as csv.
When I use

```
re.sub(r"\s+", ",", data))
```

I get

```
0,PT,TY,LAB,PAR(0),L2-NORM,U(1),U(2),U(3),U(4),U(5),U(6),1,1,9,1,3.00000E+01,1.41129E+02,1.50000E+00,-3.33011E-11,3.59422E+01,5.05825E-10,1.23750E+02,1.05732E-09,...
```

they're no more organised by lines

When I use

```
data.translate({ord(c): ',' for c in string.whitespace}))
```

It replaces each whitespace by a comma and write all in one line

```
0,,,,PT,,TY,LAB,,,,PAR(0),,,,,,,,L2-NORM,,,,,,,,,U(1),,,,,,,,,,U(2),,,,,,,,,,U(3),,,,,,,,,,U(4),,,,,,,...
```

I am wondering if it exists a way to get

```
0,PT,TY,LAB,PAR(0),L2-NORM,U(1),U(2),U(3),U(4),U(5),U(6)     
1,1,9,1,3.00000E+01,1.41129E+02,1.50000E+00,-3.33011E-11,3.59422E+01,5.05825E-10,1.23750E+02,1.05732E-09
1,-2,0,0,2.99960E+01,1.41123E+02,1.49980E+00,0.00000E+00,3.59238E+01,0.00000E+00,1.23750E+02,0.00000E+00
```

Comment: If you don't mind using pandas this should work
```df = pd.read_csv(filename,delim_whitespace=True, index_col=False)
``` and then just write to file using df.to_csv()

Comment: @zylatis I tried pandas and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your csv contains the text in your question, you can put the delimiter `,` like this:

```
import re
import csv

with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(re.sub(r'\s+', ',', line.strip()) for line in csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(dict(row))
```

Prints two lines:

```
{'0': '1', 'PT': '1', 'TY': '9', 'LAB': '1', 'PAR(0)': '3.00000E+01', 'L2-NORM': '1.41129E+02', 'U(1)': '1.50000E+00', 'U(2)': '-3.33011E-11', 'U(3)': '3.59422E+01', 'U(4)': '5.05825E-10', 'U(5)': '1.23750E+02', 'U(6)': '1.05732E-09'}
{'0': '1', 'PT': '-2', 'TY': '0', 'LAB': '0', 'PAR(0)': '2.99960E+01', 'L2-NORM': '1.41123E+02', 'U(1)': '1.49980E+00', 'U(2)': '0.00000E+00', 'U(3)': '3.59238E+01', 'U(4)': '0.00000E+00', 'U(5)': '1.23750E+02', 'U(6)': '0.00000E+00'}
```

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. it would be usefull if I obtain one dictionary each key represent one column top and the corresponding values are the different rows of the same column. However, I used the suggestion of @zylatis and it worked.